# How many lessons will/do you have tomorrow? How many lessons are you having tomorrow?

Tags: future-time

Are they all natural? As I understand it, the second one is more common, because there's a question about timetable. But the third one isn't correct because of classes are not a personal arrangement. Right?

> How many lessons/classes **will you have tomorrow**?
>
> How many lessons/classes **do you have tomorrow**?
>
> How many lessons/classes **are you having tomorrow**?

P.S. I have three grammar books and none of them doesn't contain information that Present Continous is used in any situations with timetable. It's from advanced grammar: *"We can often use either the Present Simple or "will" to talk about future events that are part of some timetabled or programmed arrangement or routine."*

Comment: As you say, the second is the most natural because lessons and classes are usually timetabled. The other two are not _wrong_, just less idiomatic.

Comment: The first is a little off, but I doubt a native speaker would notice it. The third is weird, and every native speaker will think "Foreigner." The rules of aspect with "have" are unusual and must be learned independently.  E.g., "How many classes will you teach/attend tomorrow?" is unremarkable.